# Automated email sending - most important issues

Tags: c#, .net, email, spam

My question will be a little be complex, so I will start from theory:

Actually, I want to create a software as much effective as a software using by newsletter companies. I mean, as much effective as possible.

For example, there is company with well configured smtp server (PTR, DKIM, DNS, SFP, etc.), with server admin, only without a tool, which would send emails to their clients automatically. So they use newsletters companies. 
My aim is only the "code-side". And about "code-side" I've got a couple of questions:

Q1: **What should be considered, during implementation of "Automated email sending" application?**

Q2: **What is the best way to solve them?**

Q3: **Is there any way to check if someone has put my email into spam?** 
I mean, when somebody do that, his smtpserver has to know that. His smtpserver also know where this message came from, right? So i thought.. maybe. It would be good for everyone.

---

My research:

I spent some time on research in "mass-email" subject, so I want write what I already know (there is no sens, that you will waste your time and write things which I already know). Please correct me, if I'm wrong or add some more things, which are important in that subject.

1) Bounce-backs and email error-reporting

My idea: I've got two threads. First, read messages from DB, and send them. Second, check (in timer) for new messages in inbox (via POP3 or IMAP, I think I will do both options, IMAP in better because, I don't want to get entire message) and parse them. If the message is like "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" with memo: "500 No such user", I will remove address from the list. 
In this point I would like to ask about my solution and possible reasons of Bounce-backs, maybe there is an official list of that reasons?.

2) Proper use of MIME in email messages

So basically, If the message (body) will be created in C# (I mean from some pattern), and send as a simple "text" (only with option to change to html), without any script or sth like that.. that messages will be safe, right? "MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;" - This is bad.

3) Track your Email in Real-time
This is very popular feature offered by newsletters companies. And that is weird for me. To track your email, you have to send message as HTML (not good idea), with img or sound or some component. Html Emails with images mostly go to SPAM. I'm not even sure, if that is legal? I mean to track people like that?

4) I found also sth like that: "some servers will ban you when you send too many mails close together, so you need to shuffle and watch your queue (e.g. send one mail to joe@example.com, then three to other domains, only then another to otheraddress@example.com)"
- I don't think that create algorithm to correct the address list will be completed..but Is that true?

I think, that will be it. Any answer for any of my question will be great. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider formulating your questions less verbose in the future. People more likely will read them then...

Comment: Hi @Marshall. I am sorry to say that I will have to close this question, as it is not fitting for the SO platform. You should instead ask one question per issue, and only about programming related issues. Your first question, "What should be considered", is a discussion-type question, which is not fitting at all here, and will be closed regardless. You need to do some research into this topic elsewhere, and when you have programming-related issues you're stumped with, you're welcome to ask about those. But, try to limit it to one question per asked question. Thanks.